# From where I can get a list of trusted certificates fo HTTPS?

Tags: tls, ocsp

I am using OpenBSD with a browser named Xombrero that doesn't have SSL certs by default. Should I get the certs from the /etc/ssl/certs.pem file?

(ex.: I am not trusting OCSP and don't trust that my webbrowser auto-updates itself - if there were any - so the certs aren't updated)

**Question**: are there any best-practises to get a list of trustable CA's certs?

Answer (score 2):

In any case, OCSP is not about telling you who you should trust; OCSP is solely concerned about *revocation*. When an OCSP server sends a response which says that a given certificate is "good", this is a misnomer; it really means "there is no known revoked certificate with that serial number". OCSP does not guarantee that the target certificate exists at all, let alone that it is "trustworthy".

That being said, the list of trusted CA is, indeed, the list of *trusted* CA. Will you declare that you will trust some CA because you found some list on some Web page which tells you that "you shall trust these CA", and that Web page was pointed to you by "some guy on the Internet" (who shows neither his real name, nor his real face) ?

If you really want to surrender your security to the advice of a random stranger, be he a bear, you may at least apply some personal judgement and decide on a per CA basis whether you want it or not. *As a starting point*, you could begin by copying the "trusted CA" from another Web browser, say Internet Explorer or Firefox. The CA from IE are the CA that Microsoft, in its infinite wisdom, declared fit to be trusted by the general public (the list and rationale about why these CA are "trusted" can be found [there](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125)); you may want to prune that list a bit. However, Windows' market share being what it is, it is pretty much guaranteed that any HTTPS Web site which "works" will have a certificate issued directly or indirectly by one of these CA.

(Since the Microsoft list of CA contains a number of "government CA" which were added because governments are, as a rule, narcissistic, but are not actually *used*, the list can be considerably pruned without substantially breaking Web browsing. There may be about a dozen commonly used root CA.)